# How to take list(set(aList)) values as per original occurrence order of the list(aList)?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list:

```
lst=[1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4]
```

After this code:

```
lst = list(set(lst))

print(lst)
```

I get this output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Also, I have another list:

```
lst=[6,6,7,7,8,8,9,9]
```

After this code:

```
lst = list(set(lst))

print(lst)
```

I get this output

```
[8, 9, 6, 7]
```

This output is not in the original order of the list (`[6,7,8,9]`). But I expected to get this order.

Also, I have a another list:

```
lst=[6,6,7,7,8,8,9,9,1,1]
```

After this code:

```
lst = list(set(lst))

print(lst)
```

I get this output:

```
[1, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

But I want the output as `[6, 7, 8, 9, 1]`.

So my question is: how can I take the set of a list while retaining the original order order of list? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes. It is already answered. But I couldn't find this answer while searching with my search queries. Sorry for the inconvenience.. Now I get the answer by using " list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(items)) " code.. Thank you very much..